# Multiple Audiodevices in RDP Session

Tags: windows, rdp, audio

I have bought a really nice headset. Which registers two audiodevices at my computer (Windows). This is so i can use one for music and one for teamspeak, etc. It has a little balancewheel that enables the user to make one channel louder then the other or vice versa.

I would really like to use that feature. The only problem ist, that I want to use it in an RDP session which even with RemoteAudio enabled only allows me to use one of the two devices.

Is there any way around that?

Comment: No, RDP protocol always to use only default audio device for redirecting sound from remote server to client.

Answer (score 1):

RDP provides just one audio channel; if you want to use multiple in/out devices (or channels), you will have to use 3rd party software like [Fabula's Sound for Remote Desktop](https://www.fabulatech.com/) solution.